# hx-get = "/contact/1/edit" -- is this a reference to an html file?

Tags: htmx

New here. I have some programming background in the remote past (Perl, Visual basic, C++) etc. I am trying to re-start my programming skills. So eventually, I want to learn htmx + Django.
For now though, I just want to create a simple frontend using htmx. I want to just get started with a complete example file. I went to htmx site and an example shows the following code:

```
<div hx-target="this" hx-swap="outerHTML">
    <div><label>First Name</label>: Joe</div>
    <div><label>Last Name</label>: Blow</div>
    <div><label>Email</label>: joe@blow.com</div>
    <button hx-get="/contact/1/edit" class="btn btn-primary">
    Click To Edit
    </button>
</div>
```

hx-get = "/contact/1/edit"   Does this line mean I need to create a contact/1 folder at the site directory and edit.html?

For now I am trying to use just htmx. But I am going to go through some tutorials on htmx+django eventually.

Thank you!

I tried the example code, I get a code 404 error from my local server.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: the target endpoint can be anything. It can be a pre-rendered static HTML file, that HTMX uses to update the current page's content (see [boosting mode](https://htmx.org/docs/#boosting)). Or it can be a dynamic backend server's endpoint that returns some content based on the path and other parameters.

HTMX site's example section uses a "fake server" on the client that acts like a real backend server. It catches the routes used in the examples and returns some HTML/data for them. It is there just for practical reasons (this way they don't have to host a real backend server for demonstration purposes.)

On your dev environment you want to use a real backend, like Django that you mentioned. With Django you create an endpoint with the `path` function that maps `/contact/1/edit` URL to your contact editing view function, e.g.:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('contact/<int:contact_id>/', views.contact_view),
    path('contact/<int:contact_id>/edit/', views.contact_edit),
]
```

In your view function you can check for [HTMX-specific headers](https://htmx.org/docs/#request-headers) to detect requests originating from HTMX so you can return only a HTML fragment, not a full page.